# Codeigniter - Using pagination, display only user's data from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

What I'm trying to do is get user's database of all the notes that they created and saved to the database.

I'm creating a pagination system which will display only the user's data that they created and show them in the tables.

**The Problem:** When I try to display the results (Only the user's data, not someone elses), it shows it perfectly fine. However, the pagination at the bottom is messed up.

Hard to explain. For example. I have set it so that it only shows 5 results per page. The user, however, only has 10 rows (notes). So it should all fit in the first page. The database holds data of other users too, so there are over 50. So instead of the pagination to show something like `First < 1 2 > Last` , it shows `First < 1 2 3 4 5...> Last` (The extra numbers aren't needed because it already shows all the user's data (notes) on first two pages.)

When I click on further numbers like `5` or above, it shows empty, only shows the database title for the table, because I have set it to only show the user's data, not anyone elses.

I hope you understand what I meant.

My controller:

```
$uid = $this->session->userdata('uid'); //added on sat , feb 28

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dayone/profile/notes';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('notes')->num_rows();
    $this->db->where('uid', $uid);
    $this->db->order_by("time", "desc"); 
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('notes', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('profile/includes/header');
    $this->load->view('profile/view_all_entries', $data);
```

My view file:

```
<?php include "includes/settings.php" ?>

<html>
    <body>
<div class="container">

        <h3 class="block-title block-title--simple"> Your <?php echo $site_title ?> Entries </h3>

         <?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. It was pretty simple.

Simply queried it like this: `$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get_where('dayone_entries', array('uid' => $uid))->num_rows();`